# Can I say "soni sensi" for "of the felt sound"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, meaning, case

So "sonus" + "sentire" would be "sound" + "to feel".
And "sonus" + "sensus" (past perf. part of "sentire") would be in agreement.
But is "soni sensi" correct for "of the felt sound" ?

Answer (score 2):

If by "feel" you mean "perceived" (e.g. "I feel it's true" rather than "I feel the damp cloth"), then yes, it's correct. Do note that that's only one possible option, though.

[*Sensi*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=sensi&la=la#lexicon) can mean a few different things depending on the rest of the sentence. But in a phrase like *Liber Soni Sensi*, it would be clear that the genitive here is meant. A title like that would mean "Book of the Perceived/Felt Sound."